# How are env variable stored and used?

Tags: php, linux, environment-variables, environment

How can I set up one and use it in PHP?

I am working on linux, and so far I can do `export foo='bar'` and use `echo $foo` which works, but how do I set up an ENV variable in linux and use it in PHP?

I am assuming I could use `$_ENV` in php to get the contents, but not sure how to store it, and if it will stay there even if I reboot my machine

Comment: How are you running your PHP scripts?

Comment: @tyteen4a03 I am running a php file but I need to store my database details in ENV, not in the PHP file .. if this makes sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In apache you could define environment variables like this

```
<VirtualHost hostname:80>

   SetEnv VARIABLE_NAME variable_value

</VirtualHost>
```

Or you can add it to the file .profile or .bashrc or your current shell profile file (located in your home directory). Then, each time you open your shell it will be loaded.

Comment: So, I would be able to store database details in the same way?

Comment: You could.It depends on your requirements.But keep in mind that everytime you change something in the database settings you would need to restart apache.

Comment: Can this be done without apache? Since I don't use it.

Comment: @user7342807 You can add it to the file .profile or .bashrc or your current shell profile file (located in your home directory). Then, each time you open your shell it will be loaded.

Comment: So, that's what everyone does it? It looks super complicated: But one last question, if I have to manually write it bashrc then why/how does export work in this case? I see in some repos that they tell you to export your database detail first and never to store them inside the repo... is 'exporting' these configs the same as writing it manually?

Comment: When servers starts it loads bash profile with all settings and imports config variables.You can add it to your shell configuration file, e.g. $HOME/.bashrc or more globally in /etc/environment.If you need to share database config with other applications then you use different file format to store database settings like xml or etc.